# What does this Xcode warning mean? "application executable is missing required architecture. ..."

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

When I build & run my app for iOS 5 in Xcode 4.2 for my iPod touch 4th generation (the first one with retina display), I get this warning:

> warning: iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a
>   required architecture.  At least one of the following architecture(s)
>   must be present: armv6 (-19033)

Although it warned about a missing architecture, the app runs on my iPod touch. What am I supposed to do to get rid of this warning?

This is what I see in my build settings. There's no other architecture to choose from than armv7 (which I think was the special one for the iPhone 3GS and possibly all subsequent devices): [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Manually add the string "armv6" (without quotes) as a new arch type (by double clicking the "Standard (armv7)" line, then click the + button at the bottom of the popup), and the error goes away after a "Clean", and "build".

Comment: What happens when I do this? Is Xcode then building twice, once for armv6 and once for armv7?

Comment: Everythin pre ios5.0 needs armv6 to run, but xcpde 4.2 changed the default to armv7 because ios5.0 only needs 7.  So if your target is 5.0, you can keep it at just7, but if its 4.3 and prior, you now have to manually tell it to build armv6 :/.  Its quite annoying of Apple if you ask me.