# Deploy App for iOS 4.2 (iphone 3g) using iOS SDK 5.0

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, deployment, ios5

I'm unable to install an application on my iPhone 3G using the latest version of Xcode.

My settings look like this:

[image]

[image]

What's wrong? I thought setting the deployment target would be all I need to do.

Comment: Follows this [SO][1] to add armv6 to the architectures setting.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784950/what-does-this-xcode-warning-mean-application-executable-is-missing-required-a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i had to add "armv6" (without quotes) to the Architectures in my Built Settings.

[image]

[image]

works fine. thank you

credits to [@user523234](https://stackoverflow.com/users/523234/user523234) and [@chown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784950/what-does-this-xcode-warning-mean-application-executable-is-missing-required-a)

Comment: My Architectures sections looks exactly the same yet this isn't working for me. Any ideas? I'm trying to deploy to a 4.2 iPod Touch.