# application executable is missing a required architecture. at least one of the following armv7

Tags: ios, armv7, armv6

I am getting this error while submitting for app store
"application executable is missing a required architecture. at least one of the following armv7"

I don't want to build my application for armv7 as the build will fail, because my third party library is not compatible with armv7.

Here are my project/build configurations. Pls help -
Architectures: armv6 (I removed $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT))
Base SDK: Latest iOS (5.0)
Build Active Architecture Only: No
Valid Architectures: armv6 armv7 i386

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this Xcode warning mean? "application executable is missing required architecture. ..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784950/what-does-this-xcode-warning-mean-application-executable-is-missing-required-a)

Answer (score 0):

go to project settings -> Build settings -> and double click on Architecture and add armv6 and armv7 and delete all it have

Comment: I added armv6 and armv7 to my Project settings. Nothing else there. But for my Targets setting, I only have armv7 (cause I don't want to compile for armv7). Doing all this still gives me the same error.

Comment: if you are not using iOS5 specific things try to build with Xcode 3.2.3. I was also facing similar issue with Xcode 4 and I ended up with compiling the code in Xcode 3.2.3